# Error:---can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, ubuntu-18.04, importerror, voice-recognition

I am making a voice assistant in jupyter notebook on ubuntu and I am getting the error:

```
can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str
```

My code looks like this:

```
elif 'tell me about' in command:
        reg_ex = re.search('tell me about (.*)', command)
        try:
            if reg_ex:
                topic = reg_ex.group(1)
                ny = wikipedia.page(topic)
                sofiaResponse(ny.content[:100].encode('utf-8'))
        except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                sofiaResponse(e)

sofiaResponse('Hi User, I am Sofia and I am your personal voice assistant, Please give a command or say "help me" and I will tell you what all I can do for you.')#loop to continue executing multiple commands

while True:
   assistant(myCommand())
```

Comment: Please put the question in the body of the question and not all in the title. Try and lay your code out properly as well and include it all not starting in the middle with `elif`. Then post in the full traceback error not just the final bit of it.

Comment: I've tried to clean up the formatting in your question a bit, feel free to correct it further.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess that you're working through [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/build-your-first-voice-assistant-85a5a49f6cc1) which defines:

```
def sofiaResponse(audio):
    "speaks audio passed as argument"
    print(audio)
    for line in audio.splitlines():
        os.system("say " + audio)
```

You make several calls to this function but this one is the problem:

```
sofiaResponse(ny.content[:100].encode('utf-8'))
```

The `.encode()` method converts a `str` to `bytes`, but the function you are calling is expecting a `str`. When it does `"say " + audio` if `audio` is a `bytes` object you will get the exception that you are seeing.

The solution is simply to remove the encode call and pass the string through:

```
sofiaResponse(ny.content[:100])
```

Please next time you ask a question could you copy and paste the full traceback which is part of the error message. That will tell you which line of code has the problem and what line it was called from. Just pulling out the final error message makes it much harder to work out the issue.